# Blink doesn't work (code in C)

Tags: raspbian, c

I am newbie to Raspberry Pi. 
Here is the script I want to see work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wiringPi.h>


#define LED     0

int main (void)
{

  wiringPiSetupGpio() ; // also tried with wiringPiSetup();

  pinMode (LED, OUTPUT) ;

  while(1)
  {
    digitalWrite (LED, 1) ;     // On
    delay (500) ;               // mS
    digitalWrite (LED, 0) ;     // Off
    delay (500) ;
    printf("Blink \n");
  }
  return 0 ;
}
```

When it is launched, "Blink" appears every second but nothing else happen.
I plugged my oscilloscope on the pin 11 aka GPIO_GEN0 aka GPIO17 declared as "0" as I saw in the ton of examples on internet.

I checked if my wiringPi was correctly installed, and it was. 
I would try to use man gpio but it answered me there is no manual entry for it. "gpio -g mode, gpio -g write" does not work too.

I am sure something missing but I don't know what

Someone has an idea?
Thanks by advance

Comment: Post an image of your wiring.

Comment: https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2018/25/2/1529400750-image1.jpeg

Comment: What pin do you think pin 0 is - BCM0 is a reserved pin. Explain what you have actually connected.

Comment: Actually I am plugged on the pin 11 ( Pin# in grey on this picture : https://images.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.myelectronicslab.com%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2016%2F06%2Fraspbery-pi-3-gpio-pinout-40-pin-header-block-connector-.png&f=1 )

But I also tried to set LED as 17, nothing changed 
I had read several times somewhere on internet that this pin is refered as "0" in the wiringPi library.

Comment: Header pin 11 is BCM 17. It may be GPIO0 in the wiringPi library, but you aren't using this.

Comment: Run [monitor.py](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/examples.html#Python_monitor_py).  That will show the GPIO toggling (if your code actually works).  It monitors GPIO0-31 by default.

Comment: What hardware and library versions do you have? The issue is quite typical for an old library being run on newer hardware.

Answer (score 0):

Your code using wiringPiSetup() works fine on my Pi3. Black wire connected to ground (pin 6), red wire connected to GPIO17 (pin 11,wiringpi pin 0).

https://pinout.xyz/pinout/ground

https://pinout.xyz/pinout/pin11_gpio17

I installed wiringPi from http://wiringpi.com/download-and-install/ using the git download and build.

I compiled using 'gcc -o blink blink.c -lwiringPi' and ran using './blink'.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wiringPi.h>

#define LED     0

int main (void)
{

  wiringPiSetup() ; 

  pinMode (LED, OUTPUT) ;

  while(1)
  {
    digitalWrite (LED, 1) ;     // On
    delay (500) ;               // mS
    digitalWrite (LED, 0) ;     // Off
    delay (500) ;
    printf("Blink \n");
  }
  return 0 ;
}
```

[image]

Comment: wiringPi may already be installed.  The foundations non-lite image of Raspbian should include wiringPi.